# Is there a good way to use SSL in an installable web application?

Tags: https, installation, ssl-certificate

My team's product is a web application that our customers install on their own servers. Some customers are able to get SSL certificates for their servers to protect their logins, but some others don't have the IT expertise to do that. Is there a way to automate the certificate acquisition process so that our installer can set up SSL on each server without requiring manual administration?

Our product runs on IIS and ASP.NET, but I'm mostly interested in how to get a certificate from a provider automatically, not how to install it on the server.